# What is the meaning of term "ignorance" in Upanishads and Vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, upanishads

The word ignorance is related to knowledge of Brahman or what.

Comment: Ignorance refers to maya. Duality. Your conditionings. All that is ignorance. Knowledge of brahman comes after shedding of ignorance.

Comment: It depends upon the context of where it appears. There are different Sanskrit words that are translated into English as ignorance. Need to know the verses that you questioning.

Comment: Ignorance or Agyanta or Avidya simply means identifying body as real 'I' in Upanishads, scriptures focussed on making person Self-realize or Atman-bodha. https://hridaya-yoga.com/hridaya-yoga-articles/teachings-from-the-upanishads/the-king-of-gods-indra-and-the-king-of-demons-virochana/

Comment: Thank you for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Ignorance or avidya is an Advaita Vedanta term. It hides Brahman and makes it appear as the universe. It is the same as maya.

**Ignorance (Avidya)**

> Advaita Vedanta says that ignorance of Brahman has created this world.
> Ignorance, which is the opposite of knowledge (jnana-virodhi), is not
> something negative. It has a positive character (bhavarupa).
>
> It has two powers: (1) the veiling power (avarana-shakti) and (2) the
> power of projection (vikshepa-shakti). Ignorance has the power to
> cover or veil the Reality, which is Brahman, and also the power to
> project this world on the veiled or covered Reality.
>
> The world is the product of mula-avidya. The individual ego, which is
> part of this world, is also the product of mula-avidya. Consciousness
> associated with this ego is called the Atman or the Jivatman. Between
> the Jivatman and Brahman (Paramatman) there is a thin veil of
> ignorance. It is like a cloud that does not all an individual to see
> the sun. In this analogy the Brahman is the sun and the patch of cloud
> is the ignorance of the individual. When this individual’s ignorance
> is dispelled by the knowledge of Brahman, he or she will have the
> experience of Brahman.

**The Journey from Many to One *essentials of Advaita Vedanta* by Swami Bhaskarananda**

**Maya**

> From the point of view of Advaita Vedanta, maya and avidya are the
> same. Just as avidya or ignorance has the powers, as it were, to hide
> Brahman and project something else, such as the world, on it, so also
> maya, as it were, can cover up Brahman and project the world onto it.
>
> Maya cannot really cover the Reality that is Brahman. A patch of cloud
> can never cover the sun. It only covers the eyes of those who are
> looking at the sun. In the same way maya covers our knowing ability
> and thus obstructs our knowledge of Brahman.
>
> In any act of knowing, the ‘knower’ and the object known’ have to be
> separate from each other. They cannot be the same. In order for us to
> know maya, it has to be separate from us. Individuals like us are the
> products of maya and we are all posited within the domain of maya.
> Maya and we individuals are not separate from each other, just as
> chocolate and a bear-shaped chocolate candy are not different from
> each other.
>
> As we are identical with maya, we cannot know maya. For this reason,
> maya is not only unknowable; it is inexplicable as well
> (anirvachaniya).

**The Journey from Many to One *essentials of Advaita Vedanta* by Swami Bhaskarananda**

Answer (score 1):

Well as per the **Brahma Bindu Upanishad** due to ***Maya*** it's being compared to darkness of not knowing the Truth i.e the Brahman:

**Verse**

> शब्दमायावृतो यावत्तावत्तिष्ठति पुष्करे। भिन्ने तमसि
> चैकत्वमेकमेवानुपश्यति ॥

**Transliteration**

> śabdamāyāvṛto yāvattāvattiṣṭhati puṣkare। bhinne tamasi
> caikatvamekamevānupaśyati ॥

**Hindi Meaning**

> जब तक नाम-रूपात्मक अस्तित्व रखने वाली माया के द्वारा (यह) जीवात्मा
> आवृत रहता है, तब तक बँधे हुए की भाँति हृदय-कमल में स्थित रहता है, **जब
> अज्ञान रूपी अन्धकार** का विनाश हो जाता है, तब ज्ञान रूपी प्रकाश में
> विद्वान् पुरुष जीवात्मा एवं परमात्मा के एकत्व का दर्शन प्राप्त कर लेता
> है ॥

**English:**

> As long as (it) is encompassed by the Maya possessing the
> name-morphological existence, it remains in the heart-lotus like the
> bound, when **the darkness of ignorance is destroyed**, then the learned
> man in the light of knowledge One attains the vision of the oneness of
> the soul and the divine.